# Advanced first and last sentence functions

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to retrieve the first and last sentences from database text entries.

The code I have works fine in this example:

```
$text = "He was doing ok so far, but this one had stumped him. He was a bit lost..."
```

The functions:

```
function first_sentence($content) {  
 $pos = strpos($content, '.');  
 if($pos === false) {  
  return $content;  
  }  
 else {  
 return substr($content, 0, $pos+1);  
 }  
} // end function

// Get the last sentence

function last_sentence($content) {
 $content = array_pop(array_filter(explode('.', $content), 'trim'));
 return $content;
} // end function
```

The last sentence function takes into account any trailing...'s at the end of a sentence, but neither can cope with the following:

```
$text = "Dr. Know-all was a coding master, he knew everything and was reputed the world over. But the Dr. was in trouble..."
```

Result:
First sentence: Dr.
Last sentence: was in trouble

I need to modify the functions to take into account things like 'Dr.' and other such abbreviations if that's possible, so the last text variable would come out as:

First sentence: Dr. Know-all was a coding master, he knew everything and was reputed the world over
Last sentence: But the Dr. was in trouble

Can it be done? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What do you do when a sentence ends with a `…`?

Comment: Good point! ...or indeed a '!'. I hadn't got that far yet :)
At the moment it would return "Is the first sentence a question? Yes it is.". I can live with that for now as I'm thinking more is better than less, but an interesting one I may have to address later unless someone wants to take it on here! Thanks for that.

Comment: Basically I'm afraid you will have to deal with a very long list of special cases if you want to accept any arbitrary English text. I would be as much a question for programmers as for [linguists](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It's a tough one yea, but I'm personally happy with a few 'loose' results favouring 2 sentences instead of one, should the first end in a ? or !, it's reasonably unlikely that many (sentences in a row) will all end in special characters before a full stop occurs. But having just a few letters like Dr. is not so handy. Anyway, getting into linguistic conversations on here probably isn't cool. Thanks for the heads-up tho. I better test some of the answers here so I can give some handy feedback :) (and maybe find a linguistics forum!)

Answer (score 2):

**You can exclude some word by [replacing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) them.**

```
<?

function first_sentence($content) {  
 $pos = strpos($content, '.');  
 if($pos === false) {  
  return $content;  
  }  
 else {  
 return substr($content, 0, $pos+1);  
 }  
} // end function

// Get the last sentence

function last_sentence($content) {
 $content = array_pop(array_filter(explode('.', $content), 'trim'));
 return $content;
} // end function

$text = "Dr. Know-all was a coding master, he knew everything and was reputed the world over. But the Dr. was in trouble...";

$tmp = str_replace("Dr.","Dr____",$text);
echo $tmm ."\n"; 
echo str_replace("Dr____","Dr.",first_sentence($tmp ))."\n";
echo str_replace("Dr____","Dr.",last_sentence($tmp ));

?>
```

[**WORKING CODE**](http://codepad.org/yDSzMiPU)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you thought about that..

Can you make a function to encode/decode the `$content` before you search for the sentences;

```
function encode_content($content){
    return $encoded_content = str_replace("Dr.", "Dr#;#", $content);
}
```

And after you retrieve the sentences, decode again:

```
function decode_content($content){
    return $encoded_content = str_replace("Dr#;#", "Dr." , $content);
}
```

Comment: @MrC, I know it's not optimized.. but with a few changes you can add exceptions to it, like `...`, `..`, `Mr.`... just add lines of `$encoded_content = str_replace("Mr.", "Mr#;#", $encoded_content);` for every exception before the return the string! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can check your `substr` length, and return only if it is longer than 3 characters (point included). If it is less or equal, you can use a whitelist in order not to stumble upon words such as "No", "Me", "Us", "Oh"... Scrabble dictionaries should be able to help you there :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question after putting some new functions together given the answers so far

```
function encode_text($content){
  $search = array("Dr.", "i.e.", "Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ms."); // put our potential problems in an array
  $replace = array("Dr#;#", "i#e#", "Mr#;#", "Mrs#;#", "Ms#;#"); // make them good for first and last sentence functions
  $encoded_content = str_replace($search, $replace, $content);
  return $encoded_content;
} // end encode
```

Then we just swap the search and replace variables around to make our decode function. Now they can be used with the first and last sentence functions above, and it works a charm. Adding stuff to the arrays is simple, thinking of what's appropriate to add tho is less so :)

Cheers!